# Generic class issues when typecasting in constructors base() call c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

I'm having issues in understanding how to typecast an object into its parent that was using a  generic.

I get the error

```
 Cannot convert type 'TeamTrackerExposure.TTFileUploadDict' to 'JadeSoftware.Joob.MemberKeyDictionary<JadeSoftware.Joob.JoobDictionaryKey,JadeSoftware.Joob.JoobObject>'
```

in the constructor

```
 public AC_TTFileUploadDict(DbJoobContext proc, TTFileUploadDict obj, TTPage page)
        : base(proc, (MemberKeyDictionary<JoobDictionaryKey,JoobObject >) obj, page)
    {
```

TTFileUploadDict has the following class definition

```
 public partial class TTFileUploadDict : MemberKeyDictionary<TTFileUploadDictKey, TTFileUpload>
{
 .....
 }
```

TTFileUploadDictKey's class definition is

```
 public class TTFileUploadDictKey : JadeSoftware.Joob.JoobDictionaryKey
{
 .....
 }
```

and lastly TTFileUpload's

```
 public partial class TTFileUpload : JoobObject
{
 .....
 }
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to typecast to a generic parent class, any assistance on how to do this would be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do it is to use covariant generic interface (but you still will be able to cast only to interface, not to base class). Take a look at [C# Generics Interface Covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596005/c-sharp-generics-interface-covariance) or http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Comment: Thanks Nikolay, I'm trying to get my head around it, so I could add a interface to the base class such as
`interface IBase<JoobDictionaryKey,JoobObject >{

}`
then access the objects from within `class Base : IBase {}` ?

Comment: Yes, but it should be IBase<out JoobDictionaryKey, out JoobObject >{ }. Then you will be able to cast TTFileUploadDict to IBase<JoobDictionaryKey, JoobObject >