# How to fix Cast errors when casting down generic parameters

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

In some situations I need to cast down an object to an interface to fit my needs, which implicitly requires to cast down type arguments of generic interfaces.

#### Example

`ICage<TAnimal>` is the interface for a `Cage` of an animal of type `IAnimal`

```
public interface ICage<TAnimal>
    where TAnimal : IAnimal<IOwner>

public class Cage<TAnimal> : ICage<TAnimal>
    where TAnimal : IAnimal<IOwner>

public interface IAnimal<out TOwner>
    where TOwner : IOwner
```

`IAnimal` needs an Owner of type `IOwner`

```
public abstract class Mammal<TOwner> : IAnimal<TOwner>
    where TOwner : IOwner
```

A Mammal is a type of Animal with an Owner of type `IOwner`.

```
public class Human : IOwner
```

A `Human` is a type of `IOwner`

```
public class Dog<TOwner> : Mammal<TOwner>
    where TOwner : IOwner
```

A Dog is a type of Mammal.

Now putting everything together:

```
 var cage = new Cage<Mammal<IOwner>>();
 var me = new Human()
 {
     Name = "Hakim"
 };
 var dog = new Dog<Human>();
 dog.Owner = me;
 cage.Add((Mammal<IOwner>)dog);
```

In the last line I get a compile time error CS0030 telling me that I can not convert Dog to Mammel.

Comment: Interestingly, a version of this question came up earlier today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53960364/casting-type-to-interface-with-a-generic-type-constraint.  That was found to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596005/c-sharp-generics-interface-covariance.  I particularly liked the comment on today's question (by @vc74): _If the second worked on any interface, you'd be able to call `List<Panther>.Add(fish)` with both `Panther` and `Fish` implementing `IAnimal`_.  Your case is harder, I guess you could have a `Neanderthal` implementation of `IOwner`

Comment: It should work if you use specific types in your `cage` definition: `var cage = new Cage<Mammal<Human>>();` and then just pass `dog` to the `Add` method without any casting. Alternatively, you could make both arguments generic, like: `var cage = new Cage<IAnimal<IOwner>>();` and it should also work.

Comment: @Rufus L: Is using an explicit conversion operator an option

Comment: You don't need to cast at all.

Answer (score 3):

This is the same reason why [you can't cast a `List<string>` to a `List<object>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/convert-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass).

Let's say in `Mammal` there is a property called `Owner` like this:

```
public TOwner Owner { get; set; }
```

For an instance of `Mammal<IOwner>`, this becomes:

```
public IOwner Owner { get; set; }
```

`dog` is a `Dog<Human>`, which is also a `Mammal<Human>`. *If* you *could* cast `dog` to `Mammal<IOwner>`, this would mean that `dog.Owner` can suddenly store any type that implements `IOwner`. i.e. this would be possible:

```
class EvilOwner : IOwner { ... }

Mammal<IOwner> mammal = (Mammal<IOwner>)dog;
mammal.Owner = new EvilOwner();
```

But that's not possible because `dog` at runtime is a `Dog<Human>`, which has an `Owner` of `Human`. `EvilOwner` cannot possibly be stored in `Human`!

What I suggest you do is to remove the `TOwner` generic parameter. If in your mind that `Dog<Human>` *is also a kind of* `Mammal<IOwner>`, then it probably makes more sense to design the classes like this:

```
public interface IAnimal {
    IOwner Owner { get; }
}

public abstract class Mammal : IAnimal { ... }

public class Dog : Mammal { ... }
```

Comment: With your suggestion I gain some flexibility but lose the ability to say by example that a Dog has to have a Human as it's Owner. (You could set a SetOwner(IOwner) method on IAnimal and perform some sort of type check / conversion but that's not ideal).

Comment: @Hakim then you _can’t_ convert `Dog` to `Mammal<IOwner>`. If that were allowed, you could set the dog’s owner to something other than a `Human`, couldn’t you?

Comment: You are absolutely right there, but in case of a cast from [List<string> to List<object>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817332/10195843) casting the items in it is possible?!

Comment: @Hakim I see. Then you must create a _new_ instance of `Dog<IOwner>` using your instance of `Dog<Human>`, just like in order convert a `List<string>` to a `List<object>`, you need to create a _new_ list. And after that, cast to `Mammal<IOwner>`.